# Avoid Other applications load my dll

Tags: dll

I have created a ContextMenu DLL (to dispaly icon overlay and other shell context menus) and register it in my system.

Acutally, since it is a context menu dll, I wish only explorer exe should load my dll. But in my case, applications like 'Thunderbird', 'Process Explorer', 'Visual studio', ... etc are all using my dll.

Is there any way to avoid other applications using my dll. I only want explorer exe to load my dll. Is there a way to check this in my dll ???

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What benefit does it give anyone? Note that anything with a file dialog in it may actually need the context menu dll.

Answer (score 0):

In `DllMain` you can test the name of exe file which loaded your dll with respoct of `GetModuleFileName` with NULL as the firts parameter. If a wrong exe try to load your dll the `DllMain` can return `FALSE`.